# Windows client sees IP addres, not host name

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, linux-mint

I have setup a small linux mint server which I try to access from windows. In windows I can neither ping nor map this linux mint server by host name, but I can do both by IP address. I added `wins` to `/etc/nfsswitch.conf`, installed `winbind` on the server and since then I can ping the server, but still not map it. I can access the posgresql server by IP address but want to access it by host name. The server does not show up in the network entry from windows explorer.

Anybody have any idea what I should do so the linux mint host name can be resolved by Windows (7 and 10)?

Comment: Usually it's a DNS server that allows you to use hostnames in commands (i.e. resolve a hostname to an IP address).  I had a modem+router that also hosted the DNS, but when I replaced it with a Netgear modem+router that did not have DNS, I had the same problem as you.

Comment: And were you able to solve that situation?

Comment: Eventually I put back the old modem+router.  You could try hosting the DNS server on your Linux box.